# Question about UMP tests collapsing back into a simple null?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

So my question is pretty simple.

If $\phi (X)$ is a test function that is UMP for testing

$$H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0 \space \space \space vs \space \space \space H_1: \theta > \theta_0$$

Is $\phi (X)$ necessarily also UMP for testing

$$H_0: \theta = \theta_0 \space \space \space vs \space \space \space H_1: \theta > \theta_0$$

My textbook (Keener's) seems to suggest so in one of the answers, by using the MLR property to find the UMP for the second test. I don't really see why this is the case.

Is it because the test only depends on $\theta_0$ and not any $\theta < \theta_0$?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#The_Karlin%E2%80%93Rubin_theorem) also seems to suggest so.

Comment: When doing the first form, where do you evaluate the likelihood under $H_0$?